# GitHub showing repository language as Hacking

Tags: github

[screenshot of repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7n1Yz.png)

I think this is not a huge deal for some good developers but I am just confusing why one of my github repository is showing it's language as hacking.

Comment: Looks like [this](https://github.com/github/linguist/issues/4229) issue may describe the same problem?

Comment: How a web site behaves is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hack is a language that also [uses the PHP extension](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml#L2351-L2363). You can override the auto-detection by specifying a different language in a `.gitattributes` file at the top level of the repository:

```
*.php linguist-language=PHP
```